# how to create json file from google sheets?

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

how to create json file from google sheets ?

after i want auto update or 10-20-30 min update from sheets

site. com/country.json and

**i want json structure in my site :**

```
var country_data = 
{"Canada": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 56.417  }, 

"NO": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 30.417  }, 

"SW": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 39.417  }, 

"SP": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 89.417  }, 

"UK": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 13.417  }, 

"IT": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 65.417  }, 

"GR": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 44.417  }, 
"Ge": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 97.607  }, 
 "SE": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 98.417  }, 
 "USA": {
"15-02-2014": 15.417,
"30-03-2014": 99.417 }}
```

or

**i want replace code  in datatables/highcharts**
[how to replace json data on datatables? ( I want google sheets )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70869646/how-to-replace-json-data-on-datatables-i-want-google-sheets)

please help all :)
thanks !

Comment: I see that you are a fairly new user here at StackOverflow. Please do read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first before asking another question as your post might be closed if it doesn't meet the criteria of it being a good question. Enjoy your stay at StackOverflow.

Comment: @taylor.2317 no  , my first question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70869646/how-to-replace-json-data-on-datatables-i-want-google-sheets

Comment: @taylor.2317 i want change code or i want create json file ( working json structure )  :)